# Opencv-python performs panoramic stitching, and ERR_CAMERA_PARAMS_ADJUST_FAIL = 3 appears

Tags: python, opencv

Opencv-python performs panoramic stitching, and ERR_CAMERA_PARAMS_ADJUST_FAIL = 3 appears

The picture is scaled 6 times to complete the stitching normally

Source image size: 5472*3648

```py
import os
import cv2 
import imutils
import traceback
import random
import string
import glob
import numpy as np
import argparse
import sys

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", type=str, required=True,help="全景素材目录")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=str, required=True,help="输出目录")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
try:
    print("[INFO] "+args["images"])
    dirname = glob.glob(os.path.join(args["images"], '*'))
    names = os.listdir(args["images"])
    images = []
    for name in dirname:
        image = cv2.imread(name)
        images.append(image)

    filename = ''.join(random.sample('zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba',5))

    stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False) if imutils.is_cv3() else cv2.Stitcher_create(False)
    status,stitched = stitcher.stitch(images)
    # status = 3
 
    cv2.imwrite(args['output']+'/'+filename+'.JPG', stitched)
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: We would need to see your code in order to help you.

Comment: Code has been output

Comment: did you solve the problem? I have a similar one and cannot solve it.